# Linked Server using provider string gives error "Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists" when accessing via SQL login

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I know there's [another question on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184194) that is about this issue, but the solution there from sepupic & Paul White doesn't fix my problem -- hence, a new question.

LocalMSSQL is running SQL Server 2019, specifically `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)`.

RemoteMSSQL is running SQL Server 2017, specifically `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU21) (KB4557397) - 14.0.3335.7 (X64)`.

On LocalMSSQL, I ran:

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedserver
  @server = N'Remote',
  @srvproduct = N'',
  @provider = N'MSOLEDBSQL',
  @datasrc = N'RemoteMSSQL.example.com',
  @provstr = N'Encrypt = yes;',
  @catalog = N'remoteDB'
;
EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
  @rmtsrvname = N'Remote',
  @useself = 'FALSE',
  @locallogin = NULL,
  @rmtuser = N'rmt-MSSQL-login',
  @rmtpassword = N'REDACTED'
;
```

When I connect to LocalMSSQL with my AD account (windows auth) using SSMS and query RemoteMSSQL via the linked server, I have no issues -- possibly because I also have a login with my AD account on RemoteMSSQL. However, when I connect using a local SQL login, I get the dreaded:

> Msg 7416, Level 16, State 2, Line 8 
> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.

I tested logging in directly to RemoteMSSQL using the SQL login and it works fine. So, after googling around, I came across the post mentioned above, and related [MS Blog article from Michel Degremont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mdegre/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists), which mentioned adding the `User ID` parameter to the provider string; so, I ran the following:

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver @server = N'Remote', @droplogins = 'droplogins';
EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedserver
  @server = N'Remote',
  @srvproduct = N'',
  @provider = N'MSOLEDBSQL',
  @datasrc = N'RemoteMSSQL.example.com',
  @provstr = N'User ID = rmt-MSSQL-login; Encrypt = yes;',
  @catalog = N'remoteDB'
;
EXEC master.sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
  @rmtsrvname = N'Remote',
  @useself = 'FALSE',
  @locallogin = NULL,
  @rmtuser = N'rmt-MSSQL-login',
  @rmtpassword = N'REDACTED'
;
```

This did not solve the problem. The linked server still gave the error message when connecting using a SQL login, and continued to work with my AD account.

Note that passing an empty string for `@provstr` in the call to `sp_addlinkedserver`, or not passing that parameter at all, does make it work for the SQL login -- but at the expense of losing the encryption option that I have in there now.

Have I misunderstood something? Am I doing something wrong? Any other workarounds for this situation? Any hope the MSFT will address the underlying bug?

Possibly related observation:

When I run the query

```
SELECT
  s.name, s.provider, s.data_source, s.catalog, s.provider_string
  , ll.*
FROM master.sys.servers s
LEFT JOIN master.sys.linked_logins ll ON ll.server_id = s.server_id
WHERE s.name = N'Remote';
```

the columns in `sys.linked_logins` are populated when connected using my AD account, but return NULLs when connected to LocalMSSQL using a SQL login.

Comment: This didn't repro for me on SQL 2019.  You can potentially work around the issue by forcing protocol encryption on the remote server, then the connection will be encrypted whether or not the client requests it.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Yes, I can force encryption on the remote side. But, what if I want to set ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly or some other parameters? I'm surprised that you couldn't reproduce this. Any ideas for what I could check? I'm really confused by it working when connected to LocalMSSQL using AD auth, but not SQL auth. Also, did you have to add the UserID to the provider string?

Comment: You've configured "Allow inprocess" for the MSOLEDBSQL linked server provider?

Comment: Yes, Allow inprocess is enabled for MSOLEDBSQL.